# What skills does one need to have to get started in auto body repair?

Tags: body, body-work

I've been looking into a career in auto body repair and was wondering what sort of skills / knowlege one might need to get into this field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patience and attention to detail would be the most important attributes.  The knowledge is secondary to having those particular character traits.